# No forking in IF statement

Tags: c, fork

Why are these two statements not equivalent?

If i==3 then the fork() is executed.

If i!=3 then the fork() doesn't get executed.

What is going on here? Is it some kind of compiler optimization malfunction?

```
if((i==3) && (fork()==0))
if((fork()==0) && (i==3))
```

Comment: My guess would be that once the first value is false, it has no need to check the next. I'm not a C programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the direct result of *short-circuit evaluation* performed by logical `&&` operator: when `i != 3`, `if` statement knows that the result of the expression is going to be `false`, and stops right there.

That's why it does not get to execute `fork`. If you do not want this behavior, you could use bitwise AND operator `&`.

However, the logic of your code would remain questionable, because it would be impossible to tell on what side of the "fork" you landed when `i != 3`.

If you want to do a `fork` no matter what the value of `i`, but properly get the side of the "fork", do the fork upfront, and check the result inside the `if`:

```
pid_t side = fork();
if (i == 3) {
    if (side == 0) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    if (side == 0) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If the first term is false, you know the whole `&&` will be false, so many languages skip the second evaluation deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

The right hand side of C's && operator is not executed when the left hand side is falsey.